# How does Conan know that something is cut recently?

Tags: detective-conan

In many episodes, Conan sees a tree branch or a rope and after a quick look, he states that it is recently cut which means it is done by the culprit.

How does he know that?

Comment: Not sure for the rope part. But a tree(branch) can be identified by it's humidity, color, and decay. Most of which can be seen on first glance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cut rope or branch (or any piece of wood) will start to discolor almost immediately.  If you know what a fresh cut and non-recent cut look like it is not difficult to spot anything in between.